# How can I import a jsonb column from a csv file using the COPY command?

Tags: postgresql, distributed-database, yugabytedb

I am trying to import the following csv file into YugaByte DB YSQL. Note that the second entry in each row is a `JSON` object.

```
"15-06-2018","{\"file_name\": \"myfile1\", \"remote_ip\": \"X.X.X.X\"}"
"15-06-2018","{\"file_name\": \"myfile2\", \"remote_ip\": \"Y.Y.Y.Y\"}"
```

My table schema is:

```
postgres=# create table downloads_raw (request_date text, payload jsonb);
```

I want the JSON snippet in the imported file to become a `JSONB` value.

I tried doing the following:

```
postgres=# COPY downloads_raw FROM 'data.csv';
```

Hitting the following error:

```
ERROR:  22P04: missing data for column "payload"
CONTEXT:  COPY downloads_raw, line 1: ""15-06-2018","{\"file_name\": \"myfile1\", \"remote_ip\": \"X.X.X.X\"}""
LOCATION:  NextCopyFrom, copy.c:3443
Time: 2.439 ms
```

Comment: Since it’s saying there aren’t two values in the input it may be assuming a different delimiter, try telling it it’s comma separated? Or csv in general `WITH FORMAT CSV`

Comment: Hmm, tried `WITH FORMAT CSV`, but the syntax is invalid:
`# COPY downloads_raw FROM 'data.csv' WITH FORMAT CSV;
ERROR:  42601: syntax error at or near "FORMAT"`

Let me figure out how to specify a delimiter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify FORMAT csv and ESCAPE '\'. Also, the format and escape options need to be enclosed in parenthesis. This should work:

`COPY downloads_raw FROM 'data.csv' WITH (FORMAT csv, ESCAPE '\');`

List of supported options for COPY command can be found here:
https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/api/ysql/commands/cmd_copy/